# Disable Chrome to ask for confirmation to open external application everytime

Tags: windows-10, google-chrome

We have configured chrome to open `tel:` links with Skype. One computer it does not open straight Skype after clicking a tel-link, but asks if skype should be opened (in a popup).

I tried to reset Chrome and tried to change the handler to another software to test if the problem maybe is with Skype. But it seems Chrome is generally asking for confirmation before opening an external application.

How can we configure Chrome to **not** ask for confirmation over and over?
This is on Windows 10.

Comment: Doesn't the popup have a checkbox to always allow that specific link type?

Comment: @grawity No it does not. Just "Open" or "Cancel".

Comment: Chrome developers see you as the product they can sell to advertisers.

Answer (score 52):

This can now be done with Chrome 79+. Thanks to the [Reddit link](https://www.reddit.com/r/chrome/comments/d3v4yr/dont_ask_again_checkbox_on_popups_not_available/) from @Kropotoff's earlier answer, you can restore the "Always open these types of links in the associated app" option by updating your system settings.

**For Windows:**

[Apply the "External​Protocol​Dialog​Show​Always​Open​Checkbox" registry policy](https://cloud.google.com/docs/chrome-enterprise/policies/?policy=ExternalProtocolDialogShowAlwaysOpenCheckbox)

Or edit the registry and add a **REG_DWORD** registry entry to:

```
Software\Policies\Google\Chrome\ExternalProtocolDialogShowAlwaysOpenCheckbox
```

**For macOS:**

```
defaults write com.google.Chrome ExternalProtocolDialogShowAlwaysOpenCheckbox -bool true
```

At least on Mac, it seems you need to quit and restart Chrome before the option becomes available.

**Another Method**

As an alternative to enabling the checkbox, then launching Chrome to select the checkbox, and ensuring it is persisted in the Chrome profile, it also appears to be possible to whitelist specific protocol handler URIs via the command line. This is helpful for Selenium and other automation, meaning that the URIs open without user intervention and you don't need to pre-configure the browser.

Assuming that your protocol handlers are `myprotocol1://whatever` and `myprotocol2://whatever`, you can do this on Mac. If you go this route, it doesn't look like you need to bother with the checkbox setting above.

```
defaults write com.google.Chrome URLAllowlist -array 'myprotocol1://*' 'myprotocol2://*' 'myprotocol3://*'
```

The name 'URLAllowlist' is supported from Chrome 85 onward and it is required for Chrome 100+; earlier versions of Chrome (15-85) also supported 'URLWhitelist' in place of 'URLAllowlist', but URLWhitelist was deprecated and then removed.

I have not tried this on Windows, but it looks like there is guidance on the [enterprise policy page for URLAllowlist](https://chromeenterprise.google/policies/?policy=URLAllowlist).

Comment: regedit fix works

Comment: How about Linux?

Comment: defaults write worked for me for macOS Chrome, but would love equivalent for Edge. "defaults read com.microsoft.Edge ExternalProtocolDialogShowAlwaysOpenCheckbox" says it's invalid.

Comment: For Yandex Browser on MacOS: `defaults write ru.yandex.desktop.yandex-browser ExternalProtocolDialogShowAlwaysOpenCheckbox -bool true`

Comment: The option is not working on Chrome Version 84.0.4147.89.  Any suggestions?

Comment: `URLWhitelist` is obsolete. Use `URLAllowlist` instead. And to avoid overwriting previous rules, use `-array-add`. Wich give `defaults write com.google.Chrome URLAllowlist -array-add 'myprotocole://*'`

Comment: With the help of this answer, we were able to add registry keys for both Chrome and Edige for our enterprises solution.  Those keys are `Computer\HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Policies\Microsoft\Edge\URLAllowlist` and `Computer\HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Policies\Google\Chrome\URLAllowlist`.  Best. similar example is similar to the answer @Joe Prettyman gives below.

Comment: NOTE: This only works over https on Windows with Chrome.

Comment: @Mike @jpgeek for non https websites, the `External​Protocol​Dialog​Show​Always​Open​Checkbox` doesn't work, but adding `yourprotocole://*` to the [`URLAllowlist`](https://chromeenterprise.google/policies/#URLAllowlist) does.

Comment: I can confirm for Microsoft Edge it is:
defaults write com.microsoft.Edge ExternalProtocolDialogShowAlwaysOpenCheckbox -bool true
or
defaults read com.microsoft.msedge.ExternalProtocolDialogShowAlwaysOpenCheckbox

Answer (score 13):

Simple fix for Windows - make a .reg file with the following inside it and run it:

(For Chrome and chromium Edge)

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Policies\Google\Chrome]
"ExternalProtocolDialogShowAlwaysOpenCheckbox"=dword:00000001

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Policies\Microsoft\Edge]
"ExternalProtocolDialogShowAlwaysOpenCheckbox"=dword:00000001
```

Comment: Doesn't work on Chrome Version 86.0.4240.198 :(

Answer (score 6):

**Solution for Linux**

```
sudo mkdir -p /etc/opt/chrome/policies/{managed,recommended}
echo '{"ExternalProtocolDialogShowAlwaysOpenCheckbox": true}' | sudo tee /etc/opt/chrome/policies/managed/protocol_open.json > /dev/null
```

If you are using chromium instead of chrome then use `/etc/chromium` instead of `/etc/opt/chrome`.

No restart required.

From [the chromium administrators documentation](https://www.chromium.org/administrators/linux-quick-start)

Comment: Thanks, this works indeed without restart.

Comment: Thanks a lot; however this only allows a permanent setting per site. See [my answer](https://superuser.com/a/1588146/104997) for a more general per-protocol solution.

Comment: How about Microsoft Edge any ideas? I could not find the folder etc or etc/opt mentioned.

Answer (score 3):

Found this while trying to fix the same sort of issue. My new win10 install with current chrome would ask if chrome could open utorrent, similar to my work machine asking to open citrix launcher every time I start a virtual machine.

What worked for me:

Chrome settings - Site settings - Handlers - Do not allow any site to handle protocols - DISABLED

Then when I hit a magnet link, the same confirmation box opens but has a checkbox to always remember this choice. Subsequent magnet links now open directly into utorrent with no notification. I assume the tel: uri would behave the same when selecting the app of your choice. Let us know!

Answer (score 3):

I was never able to get the Checkbox to show. However, I was able to get the dialog suppressed by adding the ExternalProtocolDialogShowAlwaysOpenCheckbox setting and Edge URLAllowlist and Chrome URLWhitelist. Having both of these configured allows the link to run without nagging.
I made the following changes to the registry. One for Chrome and one for Edge.

I put Skype in the URL List shown below; however I used another protocol that was specific to my organization.

For Edge:  (This appears to only work for new Edge built on Chromium)

```
[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Policies\Microsoft\Edge\URLAllowlist]
"1"="Skype://*"

[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Policies\Microsoft\Edge]
"ExternalProtocolDialogShowAlwaysOpenCheckbox"=dword:00000001
```

For Chrome:

```
[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Policies\Google\Chrome\URLWhitelist]
"1"="Skype://*"

[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Policies\Google\Chrome]
"ExternalProtocolDialogShowAlwaysOpenCheckbox"=dword:00000001
```

Comment: This solution was what we had to do as well.  I'm not sure you need the `ExternalProtocolDialogShowAlwaysOpenCheckbox` key if you insert the first key for each browser but we did both and it work so we didn't test without 2nd key for each browser.

Answer (score 3):

### Updated answer for Linux, Sept 2020

I know the original question was for Windows, but the answers and comments clearly show appetite for an answer for Linux too.  This is an update to
@tacoscool's [answer](https://superuser.com/a/1556323/104997) which is very helpful, but only covers the `ExternalProtocolDialogShowAlwaysOpenCheckbox` policy for ensuring the "Always open..." checkbox is visible.

If instead you want to skip the dialog for a certain protocol (e.g. `tel:...`, or `org-protocol:...` for [capturing](https://orgmode.org/guide/Capture.html) within [Emacs](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/)'s [Org mode](https://superuser.com/a/1588146/104997)) across *all* sites without any prompting, as requested by the original question, you need to use [the `URLWhitelist` policy](https://cloud.google.com/docs/chrome-enterprise/policies/?policy=URLWhitelist) for Chrome 85 and earlier, and [`URLAllowlist`](https://cloud.google.com/docs/chrome-enterprise/policies/?policy=URLAllowlist) for Chrome 86 and later.  If you are on 85 or earlier but want a future-proof solution, you can combine them both into a single file, e.g.

```
sudo bash
mkdir -p /etc/opt/chrome/policies/{managed,recommended}
cat <<EOF >/etc/opt/chrome/policies/managed/allow_tel_protocol.json
{
  "URLWhitelist": [
    "tel:*"
  ],
  "URLAllowlist": [
    "tel:*"
  ]
}
EOF
```

Presumably this file could be placed in `/etc/opt/chrome/policies/recommended` instead of `/etc/opt/chrome/policies/managed` but I haven't tested that.

You can verify that these files are having the correct effect by visiting `chrome://policy`.

Note that this is a policy which will take effect for all users.  If you want to set it per user then I think you have to find the equivalent key in the user profile's preferences JSON file, which is typically `~/.config/google-chrome/Default/Preferences` or similar on Linux.  According to [other posts](https://support.google.com/chrome/thread/14193532?hl=en), it should be enough to ensure that you have something like

```
"protocol_handler":{"excluded_schemes":{"tel":false}}
```

in this `Preferences` file (I wonder why it's `false` not `true`, but OK whatever...).  However when I shut down Chrome, edited the file, and restarted Chrome, it automatically removed that setting every time.  Maybe I was doing something wrong, or maybe this no longer works - I'm on Chrome 85.

Finally, if you want to achieve the same in Chromium or Brave, replace all mentions above of `/etc/opt/chrome` with `/etc/chromium`

Answer (score 2):

For macos execute the following in the terminal

```
defaults write com.google.Chrome URLAllowlist -array-add -string 'tel://*'
```

And examine chrome://policy afterwards

Comment: Thanks, worked for me in macOS Big Sur with Chrome 95.

Answer (score 1):

I'm having the same issue different OS.
Did Google release a chrome update that removed the "don't ask again" checkbox?

EDIT: my research is not encouraging:
https://www.reddit.com/r/chrome/comments/d3v4yr/dont_ask_again_checkbox_on_popups_not_available/

Seem like there was indeed an update that removed this feature.

-.-

Answer (score 1):

I see this is old, & I have no way to test, but nobody mentioined settting the **tel:** protocol via **Settings>Apps>Default apps>(tiny link)Choose default apps by protocol**:
[image]

Answer (score 1):

In my case, I would like to DISABLE the association of the WhatsApp Windows Application with the `URL:whatsapp` protocol in Chrome (however it works for any browser) so that the popup does not appear again.
I've tested on Windows 10.

**Solution**: I accessed `regedit` and deleted the `HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\whatsapp\` node.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't know how to get it done. I've created a simple application to make it work seamlessly for both mac and pc. https://www.sendwhatsappmsg.com/open-whatsapp-desktop

Answer (score 0):

### ExternalProtocolDialogShowAlwaysOpen

Since the availability of *Google Chrome v79* the [ExternalProtocolDialogShowAlwaysOpen](https://cloud.google.com/docs/chrome-enterprise/policies/?policy=ExternalProtocolDialogShowAlwaysOpenCheckbox) settings controls the behaviour of the "Always open" checkbox in external protocol dialog.

If this policy is set to True or not set, when an external protocol confirmation is shown, the user can select "Always allow" to skip all future confirmation prompts for the protocol on this site.

If this policy is set to False, the "Always allow" checkbox is not displayed and the user will be prompted each time an external protocol is invoked.

---

### Solution

To make Chrome remember to *always allow external protocol handlers to open links of this type in the associated app* you need to add a *key / value* pair within registry as follows:

- **Data type**: `Boolean`
- **Windows**: `REG_DWORD`

  - **Windows registry location**: `Computer\HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Policies\Google\Chrome\ExternalProtocolDialogShowAlwaysOpenCheckbox`
  - **Example value (Windows)**: `0x00000001`
- **Mac/Linux preference name**: `ExternalProtocolDialogShowAlwaysOpenCheckbox`

  - **Example value (Linux)**: `true`
  - **Example value (Mac)**: `<true />`

Answer (score -1):

the correct reg entry for me is:

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Google\Chrome]
"ExternalProtocolDialogShowAlwaysOpenCheckbox"=dword:00000001

Comment: Your solution had already been suggested twice.

Comment: @Ramhound: No, actually, there were two previous ***similar*** answers. Greg here is saying that both of the other answers got the registry key wrong.

Comment: Yup, this was the only one that worked for me, perhaps because my computer is not domain-joined?