# Chrome prompting for custom protocol handlers every time after update

Tags: windows, google-chrome, protocol-handler

We use a custom protocol handler here where I work that just acts as a file path proxy essentially so that our sales users can click a link in our admin website and have it open the explorer window to the correct folder.

So this was something that registers itself with the registry, and then when clicked on, prompts the user if they want to open the link in "sterlingstorage" (our handler's name), and asks if they always want to open it this way.

It seems though they've removed the checkbox to always remember?

[image: chrome prompt]

Any way to get this stop showing up for every click again like it used to?

Comment: Try opening it in Edge or IE, to see if you get this checkbox.

Comment: Did you try this?

Comment: Maybe this is better handled by the moderators as a duplicate question. In the meantime, there is solution here once you upgrade to Chrome 79+: https://superuser.com/a/1518982/324746

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Disable Chrome to ask for confirmation to open external application everytime](https://superuser.com/a/1525050/853277)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Are you using Chrome 77? Than you are not the only one with this problem.
https://support.google.com/chrome/thread/14194567?hl=en

[image: Chrome76-vs-77]

> This is intended The "always open these types of links in the
>   associated app" checkbox is missing because the devs discussed that it
>   wasn't right as there is no option to undo such a choice.   Can't make
>   it better than that. Sorry, I'm just here to give you information.

So it looks like for now, you don't really have an option. They removed this option because once you click the checkbox "remember", you can't undo that choice. So they just deleted this feature (as the source link states).

Comment: Yay happy to help :)

Comment: Unfortunately the source link is broken now.

Answer (score 4):

I just found a way to re-enable the checkbox on Windows.
You can follow these steps:

1. Open regedit.exe as Administrator
2. Go to the key

   > Computer\HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Policies\Google\Chrome
3. Open or add the dword name 'ExternalProtocolDialogShowAlwaysOpenCheckbox' and set it to 1.
4. Restart Chrome and test your custom protocol. It will show the checkbox again.

You CAN undo an allowed protocol, but you will need to edit the preferences file under your profile folder and search for "protocol_handler":
There is currently no undo option in the Chrome GUI.

Comment: This workaround has worked for a while, it doesn't work anymore :(

Comment: this doesn't work anymore. please add information for what version it worked

Comment: As of the year 2021 for the checkbox "Always open these types of links in the assosiated app" is only visible if
* Registry-Key: ExternalProtocolDialogShowAlwaysOpenCheckbox is set
AND
* the website is served using HTTPS

While for websites served using unsecure HTTP, this checkbox will not be shown.

Comment: @Markus1980Wien Aw dang... Is seems like this also precludes manually entering the URI, which I was most interested in :(

Answer (score 0):

https://textslashplain.com/2020/02/20/bypassing-appprotocol-prompts/ is an up-to-date summary of the changes in this area.

Comment: It's usually bad SE practice to just link to outside sources. If the link dies, we have no idea what the message was from that article

Comment: Given that this is the only accurate answer to the question ::shrug::, sure, downvote away.

Comment: Given that this is driving traffic to your personal site ::shrug::, sure, ignore away.