# Stop chrome from prompting when running external URL handler?

Tags: linux, google-chrome, protocol-handler

I've configured an external handler for `telnet://` links following [these instructions](https://infologs.wordpress.com/2015/09/05/open-telnet-and-ssh-links-from-chromchromium-linux/). It works great, but every time I click on a click chrome asks me:

> Open xdg-open? `http://<site i am browsing>` wants to open this application

I would like telnet links to Just Work without the intervening prompt. How do I tell chrome to launch the external handler without prompting?

[NB: I'm running Chrome on Linux]

Comment: See if this helps>>>>https://support.google.com/chrome/a/thread/3859524?hl=en

Comment: @Moab Thanks for the pointer! Adding `URLWhitelist: ["telnet://*"]` to the policy makes things work as I want, although it's odd that's at the policy level and not the user level.

Comment: glad you resolved it.

Comment: It's _very_ odd to be at the policy level, since it's something I can configure for _my_ company, that will actually be effective on my _client's_ computer (when I'm using their hardware)!

Comment: You can also enable the "Always open these types of links in the associated app" checkbox, and then check it once: https://superuser.com/questions/1481851/disable-chrome-to-ask-for-confirmation-to-open-external-application-everytime

Answer (score 0):

Solution in comment worked for me aswell. I'll post it.

---

Create following path and file:

```
sudo mkdir -p /etc/opt/chrome/policies/managed/
sudo touch /etc/opt/chrome/policies/managed/managed_policies.json
```

Open permissions for this file:

```
sudo chmod -R 775 /etc/opt/chrome/policies/managed
```

By default adding following content to this file should add the checkbox to remember your choice:

```
{
    "ExternalProtocolDialogShowAlwaysOpenCheckbox": true
}
```

This worked for all external website for me.
For custom link (like `telnet://*` in the question), you may need to add those links to the whitelist:

```
{
    "ExternalProtocolDialogShowAlwaysOpenCheckbox": true,
    "URLWhitelist": [
        "telnet://*"
    ]
}
```