# Disable "Always allow ____ to open links of this type in app" checkbox in Chrome

Tags: google-chrome, protocol-handler

There are several posts about people wanting to do the opposite of what I'm trying to do (like this one [Disable Chrome to ask for confirmation to open external application everytime](https://superuser.com/questions/1481851/disable-chrome-to-ask-for-confirmation-to-open-external-application-everytime)) but I accidently chose the checkbox to always allow a program I use ever day and I actually prefer to have the prompt.  How do I get the prompt back?

Here's a screeshot of what I'm trying to "uncheck" so to speak
https://i.stack.imgur.com/daIGY.png

I found this article from 2017 https://lifehacker.com/reset-chrome-to-stop-automatically-opening-apps-1820404423 but these files don't seem to exist anymore and I followed these settings (https://support.google.com/chrome/forum/AAAAP1KN0B0_FSBtFo5g_8) but I don't seem to have any handlers.

Does anyone know how to do this?

Comment: Please vote for this bug report so they add it in the UI: https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=721871

Answer (score 2):

That life hacker page is outdated, but it does give a pretty good clue. The properties file has appeared to move over time.

On my Windows 10 system running Chrome 100.0.4896.60 64-bit I found the file in %LOCALAPPDATA%\Google\Chrome\User Data\Default\Preferences

I also found it on a Chrome Portable installation - under the root Chrome portable install directory look for Data\profile\Default\Preferences

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem.

In Ubuntu 16.04, I found the Preferences file in

~/.config/google-chrome/Profile {number}/

and in

```
~/.config/google-chrome/Default/
~/.config/google-chrome/Guest Profile/
~/.config/google-chrome/System Profile/
```

Ensure Chrome is completely closed. Open the Preferences file in your favorite editor, search for allowed_origin_protocol_pairs. Find the site(s) you don't want to always be handled automatically and change "true" to "false". Save the file and start Chrome again.

Answer (score 1):

This is answer is an improvement of the above methods proven to remove the automated mac desktop app - url link association the chrome browser.

1. Find the profile path in use by running `chrome://version/`. The option **Profile Path:** should contain a path with this format `~/Library/Application\ Support/Google/Chrome/Profile {number}`.
2. Open the preferences file along this path: `~/Library/Application\ Support/Google/Chrome/Profile {number}/Preferences`.
3. Inside the file you will find compressed json file properties for your profile. Search for `"protocol_handler":{"allowed_origin_protocol_pairs":{` inside the inner curly braces you will find all the apps you have associated with specific url automatically. You can delete them or set the boolean value to false.

Psss!! you need to do this while the chrome browser is shut otherwise making edits to that file won't work.