# Disable Open Pick an app dialog in Chrome

Tags: windows-10, google-chrome, popups, dialog

In MS CRM, whenever I click on the phone field, it used to open a dialog "Make a call from, Pick an app". I add a registry for click to dial as explained [here](https://chromeenterprise.google/policies/#ClickToCallEnabled). The popup/dialog was disabled but another dialog started appearing "Open pick an app", where I had to choose an application for the tel link.

I want to disable the "Open pick an app" when I click a tel link, I also **don't want the link to be opened in any app** as we have our custom logic.

I have tried to block it by selecting `Don't allow sites to handle protocols` from [chrome://settings/handlers](https://chrome://settings/handlers) but it didn't work. It still opens the popup every time I click on tel link.

Is there any way to disable the "Open pick an app" dialog that appears on clicking a tel link?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: I have added more details to help in understanding the problem.

Comment: According to [this](https://superuser.com/questions/1481851/disable-chrome-to-ask-for-confirmation-to-open-external-application-everytime) you could work with something on command line level.

Comment: I did read that post, but that is a slightly different problem as I don't only want not to choose the application every time, but I also want that it doesn't open in any application.

Comment: Did you find a solution ? could you share it